# WCF Rest Method/Operations not Found - Everything seems configured correctly

Tags: c#, json, rest, wcf

I have created a WCF Rest following this link and it does not work for me.
I already have another Standard WCF service into my project.

http://dotnetmentors.com/wcf/wcf-rest-service-to-get-or-post-json-data-and-retrieve-json-data-with-datacontract.aspx

The WSDL display properly by the browser but I am trying to make GET or POST calls and I just get 404.

Note that I have 1 POST and other GET Method, both not working.

URL: http://silos:8085/KdtCustomerInterfaceRest.svc/CreateWooCommerceProduct

Here is all my code.

IKDTCustomerInterfaceRest.svc.cs

```
 [ServiceContract]
public interface IKDTCustomerInterfaceRest
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "/CreateWooCommerceProduct",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "POST")]
    bool CreateWooCommerceProduct(string key, PriceBookEntry productItem);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/OrderId/{OrderID}",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string OrderId(string OrderID);
}
```

IKDTCustomerInterfaceRest.svc

```
public class KDTCustomerInterfaceRest : IKDTCustomerInterfaceRest
    {
        [WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
        public bool CreateWooCommerceProduct(string key, PriceBookEntry productItem)
        {
            using (var manager = new OrderProcessing())
            {
                var result = manager.UpdateWooCommerceProducts(key ,productItem);
                return result.IsSuccess;
            }
        }

        public string OrderId(string OrderID)
        {
            return OrderID;
        }
}
```

Web.Config

```
 <system.serviceModel>

<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IKDService" />
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://kdwebservices9.kingdevicktest.com/KDService.svc/soap"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IKDService"
    contract="KDService.IKDService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IKDService" />
</client>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="webBehavior">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
    <!--<behavior name="MyServiceBehavior"  returnUnknownExceptionsAsFaults="True">-->  
    <!--</behavior>-->  
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<protocolMapping>
    <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
</protocolMapping>    
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<services>
  <service name="KdtCostumerInterface.KdtCostumerInterfaceService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="KdtCostumerInterface.IKdtCostumerInterfaceService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8085/KD.CostumerInterface.API/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
  <service name="KdtCostumerInterface.KDTCustomerInterfaceRest">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="KdtCostumerInterface.IKDTCustomerInterfaceRest" />
    <!--<endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />-->
  </service>
</services>
```

Comment: Do you get the error using http, https or both? Also, are you accessing the service using localhost/IP or a fully qualified domain name? Can you post the URL you are using?

Comment: You can get a 404 by omitting required parameters, check them too.

Comment: Just update the post.

I gave an alias but is my localhost.

Answer (score 0):

I sorted the problem removing these following settings from Web.config.

As I also run it in my local IIS not only in IIS express. 
These settings were probably added by IIS.

```
<directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="svc-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="svc-Integrated-4.0" path="*" verb="*" type="System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHttpHandlerFactory, System.ServiceModel.Activation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
```

I thought the problem was only the "< directoryBrowse enabled="false" />" but actually was the "< handlers>...< /handlers>".